# ret2libc calling function arguments order

Tags: stack-overflow

While I was studying `ret2libc`, I saw that tutorials use:

`call_to_function + ret addr + arguments`

For example I understand that if I want to execute system function from libc I can use the following  scheme:

```
system_address(that overwrite eip) + addrsssOf_exit_function + arguments
```

What I didn't understand is why we use this order if before calling a function the arguments need to be already on the stack.

If I overwrite the `eip` the next instruction called is system but we don't have already the arguments, right? What's I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be confusing indeed. What you have to consider is that you are not interacting with the stack in the same way you would if you were writing code. The stack grows down, but your data in the buffer goes from bottom to top. Also, items are popped off the stack from the bottom.

Your buffer overflow allows you to populate the stack in one shot. You will overwrite the stack starting at the bottom. So, when a `ret` is reached, the program pops the next thing on the stack, which is the address of `system()` in your case. It then pops the next thing, which is the return address for that function. Finally, the last thing to be popped off the stack is the argument to `system()`.

In summary, it just has to do with the ordering of the stack. It may help to watch the stack while stepping through the program after overflowing the buffer (using GDB or debugger of choice).